# Azure table returns null value randomly

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-table-storage

I have the next snippet of code in C#:

```
        var results = from g in this.context.MyStorageEventTable
                      where g.PartitionKey == partitionKey
                            && g.EventType == "MyEvent"
                      select g;
        var ev = results.FirstOrDefault();
```

which makes a consult to an Azure Table. This table contains more than 20000 entities. The problem is that sometimes the variable ev has a null value, and sometimes has the entity object. This occurs randomly. I know that the object exists in the table, so the null value is the wrong behavior. Why is this happening? Thank you!

Comment: Reading up on WATS, it's strongly consistent, so the behavior you're reporting implies to me that your input is bad for the cases where you're getting null back.

Comment: mmmm nop. The values are ok, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Try `results.AsTableServiceQuery().FirstOrDefault()`. If that works, the problem was that a continuation token was coming back with the query, indicating there's more data, but you weren't issuing a followup query to follow that continuation token and get the rest of the data. You should just always use `AsTableServiceQuery()` to get continuation-token following for free.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I still don't know why this behavior is randomly. Perhaps the storage does not always returns the entity set in the same order? The query to the storage has the form: ((PartitionKey eq '0000000005-0000016771') and (EventType eq 'MyEcent'))

Comment: Azure Tables always return in PK/RK order.  If you're not specifying both a PK and a RK any query to Azure Tables can return a continuation token with any amount of data.  This can mean that you can get a response that has no values returned but with a continuation token.  In this case the server thinks it's been taking too long to process the request so it's returning something to the client rather than just letting it timeout.

Comment: Thanks; I found this information very interesting, but bad news :(, I have tried:

var ev = results.FirstOrDefault();
var ev2 = results.AsTableServiceQuery().FirstOrDefault();

and both variables still get null values randomly.

Comment: Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) is your friend. If you can reproduce the problem (null value) while capturing the traffic in Fiddler, you can see exactly what's coming back from table storage. That usually helps to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Maybe try `results.FirstOrDefault().AsTableServiceQuery()`?

Comment: @smarx, calling AsTableServiceQuery() is only possible on `IQueryable <TType>`. FirstOrDefault() returns a `TType` meaning you won't even see the `AsTableServiceQuery` extension method.

Answer (score 2):

Instead try:

```
results.take(1).AsTableServiceQuery().execute().firstOrDefault()
```

The problem you are having is caused by the `firstordefault` converting the query into the wrong type.

The take 1 simply asks for only 1 row from azure for efficiency to go with your `firstordefault`.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem still persist please try:

```
results.AsTableServiceQuery().Take(1).ToArray().FirstOrDefault()
```

I have encountered a similar problem and this solution worked for me. This query follows the continuation token while a result entity is found or no continuation token is returned.

The results.AsTableServiceQuery().FirstOrDefault() is also supposed to follow continuation tokens however it does not do that. It is a strange behavior which also affects First(), Single() and SingleOrDefault(). In all these cases a single entity is expected explicitly and the continuation token is not followed. That is done only if the result is expected to be a collection.